# How can i edit blue box inside padding to vertical and put a space between the href

Tags: html, css

I want to make my content box(blue box) to vertical so I can have my navigation bar on the left side and how can i put a space between those 2 hyperlink vertically [Bluebox.Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3232.png)

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.bungkus-nav {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-top: 12px;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

.top-nav {
  Color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="bungkus-nav">
  <div class="top-nav">
    <p>Nav Bar</p>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-content">
    <a href="lemari.html">Lemari</a>
    <a href="kursi.html">kursi</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `flexbox` to make them side by side. Use `margin` to add space.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways (there are more than two, but I'll just show you two ways):

HTML (I added classes to both of the a tags):

```
<div class="nav-content">
    <a class="lemariLink" href="lemari.html">Lemari</a>
    <a class="kursiLink" href="kursi.html">kursi</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.lemariLink {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

This will add padding under the first a tag, the first link. But, you can also just add "padding-bottom" to all a tags by doing:

```
a {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

OR (if you only wanted the a tags under the .nav-content div to have padding at the bottom)

```
.nav-content a {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

If you specifically wanted the content box (blue box) to expand, you can specify the height of the a tags in CSS:

```
a {
    height: 15px;
}
```

You can also do margin instead of padding, if you so desire.

Answer (score 0):

Just add some vertical margins

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.bungkus-nav {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-top: 12px;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

.top-nav {
  Color: green;
}

a {
  margin: 20px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bungkus-nav">
  <div class="top-nav">
    <p>Nav Bar</p>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-content">
    <a href="lemari.html">Lemari</a>
    <a href="kursi.html">kursi</a>
  </div>
</div>
```